# Authentication Failed on TFS-Hosted Git Repo from Ubuntu (Windows 10 Bash)

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, windows-10, tfs-2015

My team has a TFS-hosted Git repository that I am trying to access from an Ubuntu environment. Now technically, I am trying to access it from the new Windows 10 Bash shell, but my understanding is that this is an accurate Ubuntu emulation.

When I try to clone a repo or pull an existing one in the Bash shell, I get "Authentication Failed." I *can* clone / pull the repo from Cygwin and Git for Windows's Bash shell. I can also access the TFS frontend via the repo's URL.

Most of the other answers I've seen about problems like this relate to not being able to access the repo from a Windows environment (Command line, Git for Windows, etc.) and that doesn't seem to be the case here. Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?

Comment: If the 'Git for Windows' shell is working, it is probably setting up the necessary environment parameters through its bat/cmd file, so you can look into replicating it, or just stick with it for git operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable Basic Authentication](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md) on your server and then try again.

And if you are using TFS2015 Update3, you can also configure to use [SSH](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate) for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication, VSTS has added PAT tokens. You can use username and the PAT token as the password. Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/command-prompt#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access

For example, if you use the Git command prompt to run a Git command in Team Services, you'll be prompted for a username and password.

```
git clone https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/{team project}
```

Enter a username that does not contain an @ character (for example, Jamal, not fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com). Use the token that you created as your password.

```
Username for 'https://fabrikam-inc.visualstudio.com': Jamal
Password for 'https://fabrikam-inc.visualstudio.com': [COPY THE TOKEN HERE]
```